# Duplicating rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my problem, I am trying to figure out how to make a button that will generate cells on another sheet using a number in a cell to set the number of duplicates.

So on my first sheet I use a formula to determine the number of measurements needed.

I need the button to copy a pre-configured row (row 6) on different sheets ("Lines 1" and "Lines 2") the number of times in cell (G9) plus 1 from the first sheet ("TI Setup").

And (row 6) on different sheets ("Lines 3", "Lines 5" and "Lines 8") the number of times in cell (F9) minus 1 from the first sheet ("TI Setup").

And finally (row 6) on different sheets ("Lines 4", "Lines 6" and "Lines 7") the number of times in cell (D9) minus 1 from the first sheet ("TI Setup").

I hope this is enough information, I am slowly teaching myself to do more complicated things in Excel but this one is eluding me.

I finally found someplace to start..

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    End Sub
    Public Sub CopyData()

    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Integer

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Range("G9", Range("G9").End(xlDown))

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells

    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) And rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then

    ' Copy this row as many rows as .value and 25 columns (because A:Y is 25 columns)
    Sheets("Line 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value, 25).Value = _
        Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("Y" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Value

    ' Copy this row as many rows as .value and 25 columns (because A:Y is 25 columns)
    Sheets("Line 2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value, 25).Value = _
        Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("Y" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Value

        End If
    Next


    End Sub
```

It works for the most part but I need to figure out how to tell it to copy the cells from the correct sheet.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60217321/edit) to provide what code you have so far?

Comment: Your post doesnt actually ask any questions. Also when you were writing your post there would have been examples gived that matched your question. Have you/did you review any of those?

Comment: cybernetic.nomad - I don't really know where to even start other than "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()" most of the examples I found didn't deal with using a button on one sheet to copy cells on other sheets based upon a formula on the first sheet. The few examples I found that looked like they might have been going in the right direction offered no explanations on how the code worked. I have pretty much no VBA experiance.